# When there are a blank cell in range macros exit from For ¿How avoid this?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know if this is the issue, but it's to the conclusion that I have arrived.

When a blank cell is found in range macros exit from FOR loop, but it can be another different problem.

In any case I would like to know the reason and how to solve it to learn, since I have no experience with vba.

With this code to find a file in a directory (name of route by variable strLocation that content the name of file too from column D) if column E (email column used as range) is filled then not issues, but if there are a blank cell strange things happen. Show a error message and next cell is skipped to exit For.

For example in excel worksheet:

*FILE_NAME (Cell D)*  |  *Email (Cell E)*

filename_1        |  example@hotmail.com

```
          |  example@hotmail.com
```

filename_3        |

filename_4        |  example@gmail.com

filename_5        |  example@gmail.com

When show message saying not filename in row 2 after go to end of code exiting from For each, not do the next cell in row 3. (Counting from row 1 after the header, Range E2...)

```
'Comprobador PDF
Private Sub comprobar_pdf_Click()

Dim Secfolder As String
Dim Rango As Range, i As Long, cell As Range

With Worksheets("Formacion-Acreditaciones")
    Set Rango = .Range("E2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim strLocation As String
For Each cell In Rango
    i = cell.Row
    strLocation = f_ruta.Value & "\" & Worksheets("Formacion-Acreditaciones").Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & ".pdf"

    If Dir(strLocation) <> "" Then                                  

    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found, No se encuentra el archivo PDF adjunto correspondiente a: " & vbCrLf & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & vbCrLf & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & ", " & cell.Offset(0, -4).Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Anótelo ahora y envíelo más tarde de forma manual con su gestor de correo.", vbExclamation, "Error Archivo adjunto"

        GoTo next_comprobacion

    End If

next_comprobacion:

Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Finished, Comprobación de existencia de archivos PDF finalizada.", vbInformation, "Comprobación Archivo adjunto"

End Sub
```

I expect that when a cell in range (column E) no matter whether it contains data or not and count equally as row. Since what I want to compare is the name of the column D with the name of the file in the directory, to later send it as an attachment by email.

Here is my full code: https://github.com/arv187/vba/issues/5#issue-411066359
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete the rows `GoTo next_comprobacion` and `next_comprobacion:`. Add something you want to do directly after `If Dir(strLocation) <> "" Then`.

Comment: After `End With` add this line:
`: Rango.Select: Stop`
Then you'll see that `Rango` does not include all the Rows in the filter…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to come up from bottom of sheet as xlDown will stop at first blank

```
With Worksheets("Formacion-Acreditaciones")
    Set Rango = .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(.rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
```

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: Yes @QHarr , Work great.
But can you elaborate the code? I don't see the difference between xlUp & xlDown in microsoft documentation. Why xlDown skip blank cells?


`Set Rango = .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(.rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`


`Set Rango = .Range("E2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

It's "E2:E" the fix?